# central extension implies $\frac{G}{Z(G)}\cong \frac{K}{\pi(Z(G))}.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, exact-sequence

Let $K$ be a group then a short exact sequence
$$1 \rightarrow  N\rightarrow G \stackrel{\pi}{\rightarrow} {K}\rightarrow 1$$
is said to be central extension of $K$ if $\operatorname{ker}(\pi)=N\subseteq Z(G)$. Now I want to prove that if above represents a central extension then $\frac{G}{Z(G)}\cong \frac{K}{\pi(Z(G))}.$

Please give some hints that how can we proceed.

Comment: Hint: perhaps one of the isomorphism theorems can be of use?

Comment: hint: For one of the isomorphism theorems, you get $\frac{G}{N}\cong K$ through $\bar\pi$, now if you compose $\bar\pi$ with the natural projection $\phi: K\to\frac{K}{\pi(Z(G))}$ you obtain the surjective map $\phi\circ \bar\pi$.

Comment: There's nothing special about $N$ being contained in the centre of $G$. If $H$ is *any* normal subgroup of $G$ containing $N$, then the third isomorphism theorem (aka correspondence theorem) tells you that
$$
\frac{K}{\pi(H)}
\cong
\frac{G/N}{H/N}
\cong
\frac{G}{N}.
$$